# Chukos Ha'goyim at a wedding ceremony

Tags: halacha, gentiles, wedding, hukot-hagoyim

Are there any practices that accompany weddings (and the whole engagement/marriage  process) that one has to be careful to avoid because of the prohibition of following in the ways of the non-Jews  (chukos Ha'goyim)? For example: engagement ring, walking down the aisle, white wedding gown etc

Comment: this is perhaps too broad...

Comment: Maybe [wedding rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedding_ring).

Comment: Don't serve pig. Don't have a priest officiate. This list could go on forever.

Comment: walking down aisle has a mekor from Adam and Chava,white dress also makes logical sense,so no chukas akum

Comment: Many rabbis prohibit the band playing "secular" music during the wedding. An example of "secular" music would be Jackson Five (remember them?) music. Though, I have been to a few affairs where the bride and groom walked down the aisle  to Beatles tunes. Offhand, I don't think too many rabbis there disapproved, but, then again, perhaps most of them didn't realize where the tunes came from.

Comment: https://www.ou.org/jewish_action/06/2014/mizinke-dance-tradition-folklore/

Answer (score 4):

Here is one:
Many Polish and Russian Rabbis felt that a Chupah should not take place in a Synagogue, as it became customary to exchange vows in a church, so it became Chukas Hagoyim. Many German Rabbis though felt that it is no problem, as it is done in Church only because it is a convinient assembly place, not due to religion or custom.

Comment: This would be much Mr helpful with some citations.